# Match 2nd sentence in String using regex, without including preceding break tags

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have an array of HTML code that comes as a String from a Salesforce query.

If a string in that array contains two break tags followed by a sentence, I need the regex to match everything that comes after Sentence 1. For example: `Dear {!Contact.FirstName}, <br /> <br /> Sentence 1. Sentence 2. <br /> <br /> Sentence 3. Sentence 4. ***Should return: Sentence 2. <br /> <br /> Sentence 3. Sentence 4.`

But, if the string contains two break tags, a sentence, and another set of break tags, then the regex should match everything after the second set of break tags. For example: `Dear {!Contact.FirstName}, <br /> <br /> Sentence 1. <br /> <br /> Sentence 2. <br /> <br /> Sentence 3. Sentence 4. ***Should return: Sentence 2. <br /> <br /> Sentence 3. Sentence 4.`

But, if the string contains two break tags, two sentences, and another set of break tags, then the regex should match everything after Sentence 1. For example: `Dear {!Contact.FirstName}, <br /> <br /> Sentence 1. Sentence 2. <br /> <br /> Sentence 3. Sentence 4. ***Should return: Sentence 2. <br /> <br /> Sentence 3. Sentence 4.`

Essentially, the first sentence should always be discarded and everything following the second sentence should match (not including any break tags that precede the match). I've tried the following regex but with no success:
`/(?<=\.\s+<br \/> <br \/>)(.*)|(?<=\.\s+[A-Z])(.*)/`

Answer (score 0):

```
((?:<br \/>\s*){2})[^\.\n]*\.\s*\1?(.*?)$
```

This seems capture the `sentence2~ string` to `group 2`  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/120)